# Azure timer-trigger function not syncing when deploying from VS Code

Tags: azure-functions, timer-trigger

When I am deploying my Azure Function (timer trigger) through VS Code, I get the following internal server error message after the deployment was succesfull and the 6 syncing trigger attempts are over:

```
16:15:04 maintenance-tanku-beta01: Deployment successful. deployer = ms-azuretools-vscode deploymentPath = Functions App ZipDeploy. Extract zip. Remote build.
16:15:20 maintenance-tanku-beta01: Syncing triggers...
16:15:30 maintenance-tanku-beta01: Syncing triggers (Attempt 2/6)...
16:15:41 maintenance-tanku-beta01: Syncing triggers (Attempt 3/6)...
16:16:02 maintenance-tanku-beta01: Syncing triggers (Attempt 4/6)...
16:16:44 maintenance-tanku-beta01: Syncing triggers (Attempt 5/6)...
16:18:05 maintenance-tanku-beta01: Syncing triggers (Attempt 6/6)...
16:18:10: Error: Encountered an error (InternalServerError) from host runtime.
```

I am not using python azure functions v2.

The code seems to be running and is updating my database frequently. However, I cannot see the function in the Azure Portal under Functions in the Function App.

I have already tried redeploying several times, checked that the `AzureWebJobsStorage` is correct and this seems to be the case.

Any ideas what else I can try?

Answer (score 2):

Source Code from the given [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?pivots=programming-language-python&tabs=python-v1,in-process).

```py
import datetime
import logging
import azure.functions as func

def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()
        
if mytimer.past_due:
logging.info('The timer is past due!')
logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
```

The timer trigger function is successfully deployed to functionapp,
[image]

The timer trigger function is successfully deployed to functionapp in Azure portal as below,
[image]

Check this [link](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1657) for your error.

> **Steps to create Timer trigger function in VS code:**

Create a new Function trigger with Azure Timer Trigger like below in your VS Code, Make sure you have Azure Function extension installed:-

I opened one Folder in my Vs Code and creates a new Function trigger like below:-
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

It will create a project for Timer trigger function like below,
[image]

Run your Timer trigger function like below:-

Click **fn + f5** or Click on **run > Debug >** It will prompt you to connect to a storage account like below:-
[image]

Select the **storage account** from the list or you can create a new storage account:
[image]

Timer trigger Function ran successfully like below:-
[image]

Then I delpoyed the Timere trigger function to functionapp as below,
[image]

Select the functionapp from the list that you want to deploy,
[image]

Click on Delpoy option,

[image]

The Timer trigger function deployed successfully, Click on View output,[image]

The output shows that the **Timer trigger** function is successfully deployed to functionapp as below,
[image]

The Timer trigger function is successfully deployed to functionapp in Azure portal as below,
[image]